# How to attach horizontal wood fence posts at an 15 degree angle to a 4x4 post?

Tags: woodworking, fence, horizontal

Building a fence using redwood horizontal boards and 4x4 posts. I'm very green, and just want to ask what the best way to attach the boards on the outside to one of the posts, that is not aligned straight as its at a corner.
Its only about a 15 degree angle, so thinking I can just cut the board ends at and angle so it lines up to the post, and then just drill screws in.  Any problem with that, as I don't want to put in a second post next to the first post, as that seems like overkill, and just wanted to make sure that there is not some easy and obvious other solution?
Thanks!

Comment: how is the 4x4 anchored into the ground?

Comment: You mean that the corner itself is not 90 degrees?

Answer (score 2):

So, if I understand correctly, you have a 75 degree or 105 degree corner.

I wouldn't butt an angle cut fenceboard into the post, as the amount of fenceboard that holds a screw is pretty modest. This would be prone to failure.

You could pad your post with a small strip of wood so that your fence boards hit the corner of the post and then are supported on the strip. (The fenceboards would overlap the post.)

(Edited out part about cutting the post, as there's a high probability that the post is PT.)

If it was a 75 degree angle and you felt lazy, you could just overlap the fenceboard and put screws in where the fenceboard hits the corner of the post. I wouldn't do this if you had a 105 degree angle for the aforementioned problem of putting screws through the ends of fenceboards.

Plan your butt joints to overlap nicely and you won't have to worry about putting fancy 15 degree angles on the ends.

Comment: If the post is pressure treated then cutting the post is not a good idea because it will cut off much of the treated wood exposing the interior non- or less treated wood and it will decay faster / sooner. As you've already noted and reiterating, attaching a backing strip behind the board in the void area or screwing the boards just at point of contact would be better options

Comment: Good point about the PT post! (I'll edit to reflect that.)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this if you have a good table saw is to rip an angle cut from a separate piece of post or other lumber that is the approximate height of your fence and attach it to the side of your post. It will last a lot longer and look better than most other options.